# python - reiterate on the same element

Tags: python, python-3.x

in python is there any standard way to reiterate the same element?

For example, I've got this:

```
for i in range(1, 5):
    if some_function(i) fails:
        reiterate_with_i
```

.

Of course, I could write a while loop inside the for loop, but is there any builtin for this?

Comment: why you don't want to use a while loop ? I think it's the way to go here

Comment: @Bernardostearnsreisen I _could_ emulate `break/continue` with a while loop, but I'm glad I don't have to.

Comment: As far as I know, there's no builtin way to do this.

Comment: yeah, the only  dirty way of doing this is if you add the i element back to the iterator in the if clause...

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't any built-in in python's for-loop allowing to do this. A while-loop is the standard way to go.

```
i = 1
while i <= 5:
    if some_function(i) fails:
        continue
    else:
        i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(1, 5):
    success = False
    while not success:
        success = some_function(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest cognate is to implement each fact of your desired logic: (a) iterate over four elements; (b) each iteration includes getting a successful result from `some_function()`.
Your desired semantic is, indeed, a `while` concept; there is *already* that built-in.

```
for i in range(1, 5):
    while not some_function(i):
        # Things you repeat until "some_function" succeeds
    # Remainder of "for" loop
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way, but instead of adding `while` and `continue` we can use `all` function:

```
n = 5
i = 1
while i < n:
    if all(some_function(j) for j in range(i, n)):
        i += 1
```